# Oracle Query to get the Initial Changed Value

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have this data. I am trying to get the Date when the Severity Initially changed to **5**. Rest can be ignored.

```
+---------+------------------+-----------+
| USER ID |   REQUEST_DATE   | SEVERITY  |
+---------+------------------+-----------+
|    4602 | 07-10-2014 07:27 | 2   |
|    4602 | 07-10-2014 15:16 | 4   |
|    4602 | 06-11-2014 22:44 | 5   |
|    4602 | 13-01-2015 17:29 | 5   |
|    4624 | 16-02-2015 18:27 | 5   |
|    4624 | 04-03-2015 20:01 | 5   |
|    4624 | 07-04-2015 17:53 | 1   |
|    4780 | 07-05-2015 15:24 | 1   |
|    4780 | 12-06-2015 17:59 | 4   |
|    4780 | 17-07-2015 14:02 | 1   |
|    4780 | 18-08-2015 12:36 | 5   |
|    4780 | 10-09-2015 20:30 | 5   |
|    4780 | 14-10-2015 18:47 | 7   |
|    4602 | 09-11-2016 14:16 | 4   |
|    4602 | 09-11-2016 20:18 | 5   |
+---------+------------------+------+
```

the query should fetch the data like below:

```
 +---------+------------------+----------+
| USER ID | REQUEST_DATE     | SEVERITY |
+---------+------------------+----------+
| 4602    | 06-11-2014 22:44 | 5        |
| 4624    | 16-02-2015 18:27 | 5        |
| 4780    | 18-08-2015 12:36 | 5        |
| 4602    | 09-11-2016 20:18 | 5        |
+---------+------------------+----------+
```

I am trying with this query. I am getting the first initial changed Date. However, the same user ID will be in records after sometime.

**Update:**

> The Severity  will have the following cycle: 1,2,3,4,5,6 and 7.  So,
>   once it becomes 7, it is considered as Closed. Again, after sometime,
>   the same user_id can be in records with severity 1.

```
SELECT USER_ID,min(REQUEST_DATE) FROM dbo.activities
WHERE  SEVERITY = '5'
GROUP BY USER_ID
```

Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Aleksej updated my question the Query. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "the same user id will be in records after sometime"? Do you mean that the status could change from 5 to (e.g.) 3 and then at some point later change back to 5, and you want to capture both times it changed to 5 from something else?

Comment: @Boneist the user_id has severity like 1 to 7, once it becomes 7, it it considered as closed. So, again after few days or few months, the User_id may appear in the table with severity 1 and the cycle will continue to 7. I hope, i have clarified.

Comment: Is there no other column to differentiate between the first and second (or nth) cycle in the table?

Comment: no, there is no other column for differentiate. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a technique called [Tabibitosan](http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2014/01/tabibitosan.html) to work out the results, like so:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 4602 user_id, to_date('07/10/2014 07:27', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') request_date, 2 severity FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4602 user_id, to_date('07/10/2014 15:16', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') request_date, 4 severity FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4602 user_id, to_date('06/11/2014 22:44', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') request_date, 5 severity FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4602 user_id, to_date('13/01/2015 17:29', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') request_date, 5 severity FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4624 user_id, to_date('16/02/2015 18:27', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') request_date, 5 severity FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4624 user_id, to_date('04/03/2015 20:01', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') request_date, 5 severity FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4624 user_id, to_date('07/04/2015 17:53', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') request_date, 1 severity FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4780 user_id, to_date('07/05/2015 15:24', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') request_date, 1 severity FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4780 user_id, to_date('12/06/2015 17:59', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') request_date, 4 severity FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4780 user_id, to_date('17/07/2015 14:02', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') request_date, 1 severity FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4780 user_id, to_date('18/08/2015 12:36', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') request_date, 5 severity FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4780 user_id, to_date('10/09/2015 20:30', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') request_date, 5 severity FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4780 user_id, to_date('14/10/2015 18:47', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') request_date, 7 severity FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4602 user_id, to_date('09/11/2016 14:16', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') request_date, 4 severity FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4602 user_id, to_date('09/11/2016 20:18', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') request_date, 5 severity FROM dual)
SELECT user_id,
       min(request_date) request_date,
       severity
FROM   (SELECT user_id,
               request_date,
               severity,
               row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY request_date) - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, severity ORDER BY request_date) grp
        FROM   your_table)
WHERE  severity = 5
GROUP BY user_id,
         severity,
         grp
ORDER BY request_date;

   USER_ID REQUEST_DATE   SEVERITY
---------- ------------ ----------
      4602 06/11/2014 2          5
      4624 16/02/2015 1          5
      4780 18/08/2015 1          5
      4602 09/11/2016 2          5
```

This works by first of all ordering the rows for each user_id and giving them a number.
Then we do the same but at user_id and severity level.

Once we have that, we can find the difference between the two numbers - if rows with the same severity are next to each other, the difference will remain the same, e.g.:

```
USER_ID SEVERITY ROW_NUM_OF_MAIN_GROUP ROW_NUM_OF_SUB_GROUP DIFFERENCE
------- -------- --------------------- -------------------- ----------
      1        1                     1                    1          0
      1        1                     2                    2          0
      1        2                     3                    1          2
      1        5                     4                    1          3
      1        5                     5                    2          3
      1        2                     6                    2          4
      1        5                     7                    3          4
```

So when we filter just the severity = 5 rows, we can see:

```
USER_ID SEVERITY ROW_NUM_OF_MAIN_GROUP ROW_NUM_OF_SUB_GROUP DIFFERENCE
------- -------- --------------------- -------------------- ----------
      1        5                     4                    1          3
      1        5                     5                    2          3
      1        5                     7                    3          4
```

The first two rows belong to one group, the last belongs to a different group.

Then it's simply a matter of grouping by the user_id, severity and the difference value to find the earliest value in each group.

Comment: Thank you so much Boneist, You are my Hero.. :)

Answer (score 0):

This could be a way:

```
select USER_ID, REQUEST_DATE, SEVERITY
from (
    select USER_ID, REQUEST_DATE, SEVERITY,
           row_number() over (partition by user_id order by REQUEST_DATE) as RN
    from yourTable
    where severity = 5
    )
where rn = 1
```

How it works: the `row_number` gives the position of each record within the set of records with the same `user_id`, ordering by `request_date`; given that, the external query simply filters to only get the first records of each group.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help. I have updated my question properly. Very sorry for that. with you query, I am getting only one record for the user_id even the same user_id records after some time.

Comment: Please edit your question to better explain your need. This query matches the needed result of your sample data, so it's hard to figure your need without seeing some more complex data sample